# How to do time diff in each group on Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Here's the phony data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'email': ['u1','u1','u1','u2','u2','u2'],
              'timestamp': [3, 1, 5, 11, 15, 9]})
```

What I intend to retrieve is the time diff in each group of email. Thus, after sorting by timestamp in each group, the data should be:

```
u1  5
u1  3
u1  1
u2  15
u2  11
u2  9
```

the result should be:

```
u1  2  # 5-3
u1  2  # 3-1
u2  4  # 15-11
u2  2  # 11-9
```

Could anyone tell me what I should do next? Great thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'email': ['u1','u1','u1','u2','u2','u2'],
                   'timestamp': [3, 1, 5, 11, 15, 9]})

(df.sort_values(['email', 'timestamp'], ascending=[True, False])
 .groupby('email')['timestamp']
 .diff(-1)
 .dropna())
Out: 
2    2.0
0    2.0
4    4.0
3    2.0
Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
```

To keep the email column:

```
df.sort_values(['email', 'timestamp'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
df.assign(diff=df.groupby('email')['timestamp'].diff(-1)).dropna()
Out: 
  email  timestamp  diff
2    u1          5   2.0
0    u1          3   2.0
4    u2         15   4.0
3    u2         11   2.0
```

If you don't want the timestamp column you can add `.drop('timestamp', axis=1)` at the end.

Comment: @MaxU The index also makes more sense with that. Thank you.

Comment: Could we switch the index (2, 0, 4, 3) to the previous corresponding email column? Thanks

Comment: Hey, one more question, If I remove the `inplace=True` and concat the two prompts together, the result is incorrect, why is that?

Comment: Because in that case the grouped values are for the unsorted (original) dataframe.